Not able to add body to the incoming request in cloud.netflix.zuul
I am trying to modify the request body of the incoming request.
This is working fine when the incoming request already has a body in it, but when the request does not have a body, i want to manually this body in zuul filter. This use case is not working.
This is the piece of code that i am using to modify the request. consider that modifiedBody will never be null, as this is hardcoded.
private static com.netflix.zuul.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper modifyRequest(HttpServletRequest request, String modifiedBody) {
return new HttpServletRequestWrapper(request) {
    @Override
    public byte[] getContentData() {
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            data = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getContentLength() {
        return body.getBytes().length;
    }

    @Override
    public long getContentLengthLong() {
        return body.getBytes().length;
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() {
        return new ServletInputStreamWrapper(body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
};

}
//This is the caller
context.setRequest(modifyRequest(context.getRequest(), modifiedRequest.toString()));
Can anyone provide any suggestion on this?

please format the code

Code not formatted properly
